# Integrating adjoint representation over compact Lie group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

Let $ G $ be a compact Lie group. Let $ M \in Lie(G) $. Is there a well known formula for
$$
\int_G Ad_g(M)
$$
where $ \int_G $ is an integral with respect to the Haar measure? For example can this integral be expressed in terms of $ M $ in some way? For example a formula like
$$
\int_G Tr(kg) Ad_g(M)=[k,M]
$$

Answer (score 2):

This may not be a "formula" per se, but it may be useful to understand the expression.

Let $G$ be a compact Lie group acting on a vector space $V$, and let $V_0\subseteq V$ be the subspace of elements fixed by this $G$-action. Define a function $\pi_0:V\to V$ by
$$
\pi_0(v)=\int_Gg\cdot v\ dg
$$
(where $dg$ is the normalized Haar measure) and note that $\pi_0(v)$ is always $G$-invariant. Using this, you can show that $V$ splits into a direct sum of subrepresentations $V=V_0+V_1$, and that $\pi_0$ is exactly the projection onto the first factor.

Using this description to comupute $\pi_0$ in concrete cases is somewhat circular, but it gives some useful information when applied to the adjoint representation. For instance, we know that $\pi_0$ is a projection onto $\operatorname{Lie}(Z(G))$, which uniquely specifies it for some simple cases like $T^n$ and $SO(n)$.

Comment: Very interesting. You said there is extra information that can be obtained for simple cases like $ T^n $ and $ SO(n) $. Do you know what the integral(s) above evaluate to for the simple case $ G=SO(3) $?

Comment: @IanGershonTeixeira $\text{Lie}(Z(T^n))=\text{Lie}(T^n)$, so $\pi_0$ is the identity there.  For $n>2$, $\text{Lie}(Z(SO(n)))=0$ so $\pi_0=0$.